# firebase authentication identifier is a dash instead of email address

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am authenticating with Firebase Authentication, and today I noticed add identifiers from Nov become a dash instead of email address

This is my code how I am authenticating

```js
$scope.loginToFacebook = function () {
        GoogleAnalytics.trackView('Home/LoginToFBClick');

        firebase.auth().setPersistence(firebase.auth.Auth.Persistence.LOCAL).then(function () {

            var provider = new firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider();

            return firebase.auth().signInWithRedirect(provider)
                .then(function () {
                    return firebase.auth().getRedirectResult();
                }).then(function (result) {
                    // This gives you a Google Access Token.
                    // You can use it to access the Google API.
                    var token = result.credential.accessToken;
                    // The signed-in user info.
                    var user = result.user;

                })
        }).catch(function (error) {
            NotificationService.error(error.message || error);
        });
    };
```

any idea why it's happening?

[image]

Comment: If the Firebase console doesn't display what you expect, I suggest contacting Firebase support directly.  https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support

Comment: @DougStevenson I already did, since others maybe facing same issue before this is why I posted in SO as well

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found what was wrong, seems needed to ask for email explicitly

```
    var provider = new firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider();
    provider.addScope('email');
```

Comment: But why you can still get email from facebook and google in the last two users?

Comment: @damingzi if you look at dates, seems fb and google api was giving email address by default without explicitly request for that in the past, then I guess they applied more restrict rules

Comment: Yah, got it. It makes sense!